# Replace content in Wordpress Page after GET from php page

Tags: php, pages, theme-customizer, remote-login

I have a wordpress Page with an html form where i get username and password from my customers.

Then i send to an external php page located in another my server and get the result from inserted credential to check if the user is really allowed to see protected content.

What i am trying to do after login succeded is to replace the current content of wordpress page (the html form) with something else, without change page and without make it external (i want to show to the user the same style of the page).

There is a a sort of dynamic frame or something else that to allow me that?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Is it possible that after successful login user is directed to other page of the site? May be send a "redirect" field in the login form? There are multiple solutions to this but It would be better if login page is separate from the dashboard page.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think to this solution but i want to keep secret the address of the page after successful login.

Comment: You can encode or encrypt the redirected page and decode it on successful login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reread your question and revised the solution as well. It is a Page template now and should be set to the page that needs its content protected. It relies on a "login" post that has the html from.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Protected Page
*/


// Standard HTML of Theme

    global $post;

    // check if authentication has been made
    if( verifyAuthentication($_POST['authCode']) ) {

        // display protected content
        the_content();
    }       
    else {

        // fetch the login form html from "login" post. Or you can read from a file or some admin settings of your plugin.
        $login_post = get_post( url_to_postid("login") );

        // display the html form
        echo apply_filters('the_content',$login_post->post_content );
    }


// Standard HTML of Theme
```

Post parameter `authCode` is supposed to be present and valid when login has been successfully authenticated.

Comment: To test this i need to implement a new template of the page, and perform it there right? If you can give more info i will be grateful. :)

Comment: You need to put in your functionality plugin or `functions.php` of your theme.

Comment: This solution can work using the Wordpress Login system. My situation is different so it doesn't work..

Comment: I think, I mis-understood your problem earlier. I changed the above solution to a page template. My understanding is, you want to password protect the post/page contents and should be displayed on authentication by an external page.

Comment: This solution can work, i will test. Just to clarify this is the schema that i want: USER TYPE CREDENTIALS IN MY HTML FORM -> EXTERNAL PHP PARSE DATA -> PHP GIVE BACK RESULT IN HTML FORMAT -> I SHOW THE CONTENT IN CURRENT PAGE REPLACING THE ORIGINAL HTML FORM. Hope it helps.

Comment: how "PHP GIVE BACK RESULT IN HTML FORMAT" is carried out?

Comment: Currently i print out the resul with echo statement but i can change to POST the entire page back if this can help me to reach my goal. Do you have any idea? Thanks for trying help me.

Comment: If you do not have any better solution except to posting a full html back to this page, you can `echo $_POST['postback_html']` instead of `the_content()` and keep the `authCode` to verify authenticity of the request to make sure that request did not came from an unkown source. NOTE: YOU MUST AVOID AS MUCH AS POSSIBLE TO DISPLAY HTML DIRECTLY FROM A POST/GET VARIABLES. IF THERE IS NO OTHER WAY, CONFIGURE TOP-NOTCH SECURITY LAYER TO DO THAT.

Comment: My "allowed" customer are time limit. In the external php i check for inserted credential and for time validity (monthly fee). Give a full html back to the page was my best idea. If you have a better idea to implement a better solution tell me please. I vote your answer as solution.

Comment: My solution would be to expose an authentication service on external server and WordPress collects and verify the credentials (through that service) and respond accordingly. So, external server only authenticate if the credentials are valid or not. All HTML should be generated on WordPress.

Comment: Can you list me some links where i can study how to perform that please? Thanks very much for your kindly.

Comment: Look for `oAuth` which is very popular and robust, most probably, you will find a library set for the framework you are using on external server. Or, you can create your own service that gets the parameters and echos 0 or 1 for valid and invalid requests. It all depends on your application.

Comment: I saw that there is a plugin called WP OAuth Server. I think that i should implement that in my server. The hard thing for me will be react and display custom content depends in server replies (it's my first website with Wordpress where i require custom login and custom content). Thanks very much M-R i think that i need to study a bit now.